# What is this Error{ MongoNetworkError: connection 0 To 127.0.0.1:8080 closed}?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is my code. I want to connect to Mongodb, but issue the `{MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to 127.0.0.1:27017 closed}` error.

```
 MongoClinet.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/demo",{ useNewUrlParser: true},(err,db)=>{
        if(err)
            console.log(err.toString());
        else{
            console.log("Connected");
        }
    });


MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 closed
MongoNetworkError: connection 1 to localhost:27017closed
MongoNetworkError: connection 2 to localhost:27017 closed
```

Comment: default port for `mongodb` is `27017`

Comment: Are you starting your Mongo server before trying to connect to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `mongod.lock` and (re)start `mongod` server.

Comment: You can explain more precisely؟؟

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem has been resolved

Comment: @Ashkanhaghshenas what is the explanation, what happend here?